# In jquery, how is it possible to randomize an Array with conditions?

Tags: jquery, arrays, random, conditional-statements

I randomize the order of my array like this:

```
var arr = [ "A","B","C","D","E","F" ]
arr.sort(function() { return 0.5 - Math.random() });

// produces for example : [ C, E, A, F, D, B ]
```

But I **don't** want the "F" in fourth position (for example).

What is the solution ?

Comment: After your randomization, go through and change any condition you don't like.

Comment: What position should `F` be at ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could remove `"F"` from array using `.pop()` before calling `.sort()` , use `.splice()` to reinsert `"F"` at any position except index `3` of `arr`
using a second array that contains all indexes of `arr` excluding `3`

```js
var arr = [ "A","B","C","D","E","F" ];
var not = [0,1,2,4,5];
var f = arr.pop();
arr.sort(function() { return 0.5 - Math.random() });
var p = not[Math.floor(Math.random() * not.length)];
arr.splice(p, 0, f);
document.body.innerHTML = arr.join(" ")
```

Comment: Nice solution ! I have just a little problem : in the "splice", the "p+1" force an index [4]. I want any index EXCEPT the [3]...the [0], the [1], the [2], the [4] or the [5],

Comment: Nice solution ! I have just a little problem : in the "splice", the "p+1" force an index [4]. I want any index EXCEPT the [3]... //  The [0], the [1], the [2], the [4] or the [5] are good too.